# concatenate 2 columns data to use as a one as a condition in joining statement(Snowflake procedure)

Tags: javascript, mysql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on the snowflake procedure.

I have 2 tables i.e `ASSET_DEC` table and `ASSET_DATA` table.

The column `serviceid_versionid` is there in `ASSET_DATA` having value like `1234_5678`.

Now, the column in `ASSET_DEC` are `serviceid`(value = 1234) and `versionid`(value = 5678).
I need to write a query where I need to join these 2 tables with the condition like

```
left outer join logs.public.ASSET_DATA asd1 on asd1.serviceid_versionid = concat_ws('_',ASSET_DEC.serviceid,ASSET_DEC.versionid).
```

The error I am getting on using concat_ws is:

```
JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in PROD_TEST at 
'"left outer join logs.public.ASSET_DATA asd1 on asd1.serviceid_versionid = concat_ws('_',ASSET_DEC.serviceid,ASSET_DEC.versionid) ";' position 124
```

How can I achieve this inside the snowflake procedure?

**Update** after @nick pointed out:

**New Error Message**:

```
Execution error in store procedure PROD_TEST: SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 1,527 invalid identifier '_' At Snowflake.execute, line 66 position 20
```

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the single quotes in `'_'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use expression as part of `ON` condition inside JavaScript stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PUBLIC.ASSET_DATA(serviceid_versionid  VARCHAR)
AS
SELECT '1234_5678';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PUBLIC.ASSET_DEC(serviceid INT, versionid INT)
AS
SELECT '1234', '5678';
```

Proc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test1 ()
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

var sql_stmt = `
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test
AS
SELECT serviceid_versionid, serviceid, versionid
FROM PUBLIC.ASSET_DATA asd1
LEFT JOIN PUBLIC.ASSET_DEC ASSET_DEC
ON asd1.serviceid_versionid = concat_ws('_',ASSET_DEC.serviceid,ASSET_DEC.versionid)
`;

var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText:sql_stmt} );
var rs = statement.execute();
 $$;
```

Test:

```
CALL test1();

SELECT * FROM test;
```

[image]